# I used True Strength index in my regular chart? Can I use it in cryptoscreener of the tradingview?

Tags: pine-script, trading, tradingview-api

I am try to find true strength index indicator in the parameter of crypto screener of the trading view to give me an alert for all currency.

Can you please let me know how I can use it.

All Respect
Ahmad Saleh

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find it either here: https://www.tradingview.com/crypto-screener/
The alternative is using the True Strength indicator and setting alerts manually on the assets X Timeframes you want to trade